# Node-slack web api: chat.delete returns channel_not_found for all channels although channels.list returns all channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, botkit

I have been working on a simple chat bot using the slack-node web api and botkit, but am having some trouble using the chat.delete functionality. I am able to list out all of my channels properly, seeing their channel Id's and names, but when I try to send along the message channel with the chat.delete function, it returns "channel_not_found".

I have also tried to send along the channel name, testing with "general" and the actual channel name that I am targeting, both of which return the same error.

My bot is using a token of the admin user, which should allow deletion of any message. My bot has scope access for chat:write:bot and chat:write:user as well.

Below is a snippet of my code - I have also tried this in other places for deleting messages sent directly from the bot and get the same error, so I don't believe it has to do with permissions. I've looked into the docs and the usage seems to be correct for what I have below, but I may be missing a piece.

```
controller.on('ambient', function(bot, message) {

      web.channels.list().then((res) => {
        console.log(res); // this prints out all of the channels
        // listed channels show a match for the channel ID given in message.channel
      });

      // this call returns an error "error: Response not OK:  channel_not_found"
      web.chat.delete(message.channel, message.ts).then((res) => {

         console.log(res + " was deleted bc it was not tagged");

      }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are a bit confusing on this, but the chat.delete method of the official @slack/client library take the parameters in a different order:

You'll want to change your code to be:

```
web.chat.delete(message.ts, message.chanel).then(...)
```

See here:
https://slackapi.github.io/node-slack-sdk/reference/ChatFacet#ChatFacet+delete

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `chat.delete` API accepts named arguments.

This is working for me, using `@slack/web-api` package v6.10.0

```
const { WebClient } = require("@slack/web-api");

const webClient = new WebClient(SLACK_BOT_TOKEN);

await webClient.chat.delete({ channel: channelId, ts: timestamp }).catch(...)
```